# Is there any way to block permissions on apps?

Tags: permissions, application-manager, privacy

I read about being [able to revoke permissions on CyanogenMod](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/05/22/cyanogenmod-adds-support-for-revoking-and-faking-app-permissions/), but it seems the devs took that ability out.

I found some app out on the market for 6$ or so, but it doesn't look like it would be worth its price. It is called [Permissions Denied](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stericson.permissions.donate&hl=en). Any other way to block some permissions for some apps?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revoke App Permissions Without Root?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/revoke-app-permissions-without-root)

Comment: @AlEverett Not exactly. This questions asks about *blocking* them, whilest the other wants to *remove* them. To be more precise: The other is about tampering with the `.apk` to manipulate the `Manifest` -- while this one simply wants to block the access without manipulating the `.apk`. So they are *related*, yes -- but not *identical*.

Comment: Another potential duplicate: [Is it possible to install an app and exclude some of its requested permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3091)

Comment: @Izzy: Is that a meaningful difference, though? The end-game is still the same: install an app but only give it some of the permissions it wants.

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes and no. If you modified the `.apk`, you won't get updates -- and also might violate the developers' rights/licenses. You might think of it as two different approaches to the same goal (I can follow that), but to me it's still two different things. Part of it would be firewalls: would you put such a request to the same process (removing the permission from the `.apk` being similar to using a software firewall to block internet access)? We might better discuss this at another place (Meta or chat) to not clutter things here, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two different solutions available for it: [LBE Privacy Guard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.security.lite) (careful when you're already running JellyBean: do not use the Playstore version then, but rather check with [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1422479), as the playstore version causes boot-loops with JellyBean and the dev did not even place a note for it), and [PDroid Privacy Protection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacy.pdroid) / [PDroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.digitalfeed.pdroidalternative). The latter is more difficult to install, but often preferred: being implemented at OS level, it offers more security.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Xposed installer and xposed App settings from XDA Xposed installer and tutorial http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401 , Xposed App Settings download. "http://mohammadag.xceleo.org/public/Android/Xposed/"

once enabled, the Xposed App settings let's you edit things about an app like the UI size (tablet or phone), keeping an app in memory and also editing the permissions an app is given.
and best of all its free

Answer (score 0):

The permissions manager feature was removed from CyanogenMod 9.0 - and hasn't been re-added.

There used to be a free version of permissions denied, however it was removed. I tried the free version and it worked well - I am unable to comment on the paid version however.

If you are using CyanogenMod 7, then you can use the permissions manager - enabled it in CyanogenMod settings, and disable permissions by clicking them when viewing an app in the Android app manager.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an app called "Android Permission Blocker" that is only 99 cents!  You need a rooted phone to use it which is standard with permission blocking apps (i.e. Permission Denied app the original question mentioned).  FOr 99 cents, you can't go wrong.  I don't have a rooted phone, but my friend uses "Android Permission Blocker" and said it works well for him for what it's worth.