# Restricting app permissions

Tags: permissions

If the specification for a given app states that a given permission is required, e.g., [Noise Meter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pjw.noisemeter) requires *control vibration*:

1. Is there a way to instruct Android to not give the permission to the app, once installed? (perhaps at the expense of a malfunctioning app).
2. Does this depend on which permission we are talking about? (perhaps network access permission can be restricted, e.g., and other permissions can't).
3. Can this be applied at the "Category" level? In each app description in Play I have seen permissions "grouped" by category... I still do not know if that categorization has any effect on what can or cannot be done, or if it is just for convenience of reading, developing, etc.

**Related**:

1. [Is there any way to block permissions on apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41714/is-there-any-way-to-block-permissions-on-apps)

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: @beeshyams - No.

Comment: Try [Pmx](https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX) developed by [Irfan](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/218526/Irfan-Latif) that works better with root or with adb without root // see [help](https://mirfatif.github.io/PermissionManagerX/help/help) //As you rightly guessed all permissions cannot be restricted this way e.g Internet for which you have separate solutions like Firewall

Comment: @beeshyams - I will digest your answer... In the meantime, it seems that e.g. network access can be restricted by means of a separate app, but not from within OS or affected-app configuration, right?

Comment: Right. Also point3, you have to deal with each permission on its own, can't club at category level

Comment: @beeshyams - Great. I am learning about Android, and concerned about privacy... Now posted as a specific question on its own https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242692/permissions-categories-do-they-have-any-practical-implication