# Disable an app from creating bookmarks

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean, permissions, bookmarks

Recently I have observed some of the apps (Photo editors) asking for permissions like 'creating bookmarks' at the time of installation from google play.

How can I disable a particular application from creating a bookmark on the home screen, like in disabling notifications on per app basis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Play Store does have an option in its central settings for controlling whether shortcuts on your home screen are automatically created for apps when you install them:

[image: Play Store settings]

You can get here by opening the **Play Store**, pressing the <kbd>Menu</kbd> button on your phone (or the "three dots" menu icon if you don't have a hardware menu button) and select **Settings**, you should then see the "**Auto-add widgets**" setting that you can enable or disable.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Learned a new thing.
But the one which I am looking for is different. Some free apps create random bookmarks on the home screen for advertising. Is there a way to disable that permission specific to the app as in disabling the notification per app.

Comment: In that case you might be interested in these previous questions: [Is it possible to install an app and exclude some of its requested permissions?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/) or [Revoke App Permissions Without Root?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/)