# Can I mark read SMS messages as unread in 2.2?

Tags: sms

I've just switched to a Samsung Galaxy Europa from a push-button Sony Ericsson K660, and already I'm finding a few features in the old device that I'm missing in the new one. For example, sometimes when I read a text message, I'd prefer to reply to it later. On the K660 I'd read the message, then return back to the inbox listing and mark the message as 'unread'. This adds the envelope icon back on the taskbar, and renders the message title in bold, so I know to respond to it later.

However some research on the web doesn't turn up much, and I wonder whether this isn't included in the stock messaging application. I'm running version 2.2. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not think you can do that with the stock messaging app. Might be best to install an alternative app to do that... let me look for that question elsewhere here...

Comment: There's handcent-sms (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms), and go-sms(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) mentioned in the tags, also there's Chomp(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms) as well.

Comment: Incidentally, I should point out that [I prefer apps with extremely limited permissions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24041/is-there-an-android-calendar-with-limited-security-permissions) and yet those apps all want the moon on a stick. I'd prefer (and would pay for) a SMS/MMS app that just used the "<action> SMS" and "read contact data" permissions... I will explore the market!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not think you can do that with the stock messaging app. Might be best to install an alternative app to do that. There's three alternative popular ones available from Google Play.

There's [handcent-sms](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms), [go-sms](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) mentioned in the tags, also there's [Chomp-Sms](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.p1.chompsms) as well.

As for permissions yeah, that's a tricky one, as long as they don't have the over-usage of permission demands, you should be pretty ok.

As an off-topic, I do know that in CyanogenMod, there is a setting to deselect the permissions as required for each and every app you install, for example, an app called 'FooSms' - uncheck 'Read SMS', the app may bomb out with an Security Error exception due to the said permission being revoked. Incidentally, there is CM7 available for Europa via [Madteam](http://madteam.co).

Comment: Thanks again for your answers. As a new smartphone user it didn't occur to me that something as basic as SMS messaging might be available in a different app!

Comment: That's the beauty of Android, an alternative customized app for your own liking that can easily replace stock android apps :)

Comment: As for total re-modding, I'm a bit nervous about that. I'm happy to root the device using the default firmware, since I believe it's 99% easy and safe. I would assume however that swapping the whole ROM image carries a bigger risk of turning the device into a paperweight!

Comment: That's a question that I must dispel the myth about it... in fact, Samsung devices are *impossible* to brick!

Comment: Wow, that's very handy to know. How is it implemented - is there a _hard reset_ or something where you can always get back to a stock ROM? (I'm thinking of what would happen if one flashed it with a build for a CPU that uses a different byte order, for example - I'd expect total system crash and no mechanism to boot up enough services to try reflashing again.)

Comment: Not hard reset, really, its a re-flash - with either Odin or Heimdall! A lot of roms that are built are cross-compiled targetting the architecture of the chipset (so there would be no such different byte order) The only true and tried tested method of doing damage is to disconnect the cable halfway during the flash, then you're totally kaput and screwed. For that to be restored, would have to be JTAG'ged by disassembling the handset to get at the JTAG pins, make the connection with specialized JTAG cable and perform a complete flash.

Comment: That is outside of the scope of this forum and beyond (am not an electrical whiz so would not have an earthling of a clue in how to do that - if it happened to me, I'd gladly pay someone else to do that for me :) ) IT happened to me once and learnt from that and was out of 50euro in pocket as result!

Comment: Well, that's all most interesting - and good to hear that bricked phones can be rescued for less than the price of a new phone! I think I will start off with a stock rooted ROM, but your response does give me confidence to try it. Once I'm sure my local phone backups are working, I may give that a go...